# Can we have a Route by default in Vue.js like Asp.net MVC?

Tags: vue.js, controller, vue-component, vue-router, actionresult

In Asp.net MVC by default a Route as

```
routes.MapRoute (
                 name: "Default",
                 url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                 defaults: new
                 {
                     controller = "Dashboard",
                     action = "Home",
                     id = UrlParameter.Optional
                 },
                 namespaces: new string [] {"***.Controllers"}
                 ).DataTokens ["area"] = "Main";
```

It is written by default and the rest of the routes in the project are determined in the `controllers` section with `ActionResults`. Is this possible in **Vue.js** or should all the routes and `components` be introduced to `createRouter`?

**As follows:**

```
import {createRouter, createWebHistory} from "vue-router";
import App from "@/App";
import App from "@/Post";

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes: [
        {path: '/', component: App},
        {path:'/post',component:Post}
    ]
});

export default router;
```

**I want all the routes to run inside the route without introducing their component and the page to be changed, is this possible?**

Answer (score 0):

In `vue-router` you can create a route that handles all path that is not listed in your routes config

```
{
  path: '*',
  redirect: '/post', // for example
}
```

Or without redirect, if you don't want to change the user URL

```
{
  path: '*',
  component: Post,
}
```